# NIO создание и удаление папок и файла

Tags: java

ковыряю NIO и столкнулся с проблемой, точнее с двумя.
**1)** создание папки files в корне проекта и две вложенные папки с файлом в последней.

```
    Path pathDir = Path.of("files", "firstDir", "secondDir");
    Path pathFile = Path.of("files", "firstDir", "secondDir", "file.txt");

    Files.createDirectories(pathDir);
    Files.createFile(pathFile);
```

можно это как-нибудь объединить в одно выражение, чтобы не создавать раздельно папки и файлы?

**2)** удаление папок и файла

```
    Files.deleteIfExists(pathFile); //удаляет только файл
    Files.deleteIfExists(pathDir); // удаляет только последнюю папку secondDir
```

удаляет по одному элементу,  как удалить все папки и файл сразу?

нашёл такой пример, но он тоже удаляет только файл

```
     Files.walk(pathFile)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .forEach(File::delete);
```

и этот вариант удаляет только один файл

```
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(pathFile, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("delete file: " + file.toString());
                Files.delete(file);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                Files.delete(dir);
                System.out.println("delete dir: " + dir.toString());
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

помогли ребята с ангоязычного сайта.

```
  public static boolean deleteDirectory(File directoryToBeDeleted) {
        File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();
        if (allContents != null) {
            for (File file : allContents) {
                deleteDirectory(file);
            }
        }
        return directoryToBeDeleted.delete();
    }
```

вызываем

```
  deleteDirectory(Path.of("files").toFile());
```

также можно

```
 Files.walk(Path.of("files"))
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .forEach(File::delete);
```

проблема была в том, что надо передавать не весь путь, а путь к первой папке